# Product of vector bundles.

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, vector-bundles, poisson-geometry

If $\pi_1:E_1\to M$ and $\pi_2:E_2\to M$ are two vector bundles over $M$, then we can construct a new vector bundle $E_1\oplus E_2$ by declaring the fibre at each $x\in M$ to be $(E_1\oplus E_2)_x:=(E_1)_x\oplus(E_2)_x$. One usually calls this (to my knowledge) the Whitney sum of $E_1$ and $E_2$. One could denote this by $E_1\times E_2$, but this seems rather unnecessary.

My question: if I encounter the notation $E_1\times E_2$, could any other vector bundle than the Whitney sum bundle be meant? The question popped up when considering Dirac structures on a manifold $M$, and the considering two Dirac structures on $M$ and their product $L_1\times L_2$.

Comment: I would assume $E_1 \times E_2$ refers to the tensor product $E_1\otimes E_2$ (which, like the Whitney sum, has fibers $(E_1\otimes E_2)_p = (E_1)_p \otimes (E_2)_p$, and satisfies local triviality for the same reason).

Comment: Sometimes people construct the product bundle on $M \times N$, but if the bases are the same the notation you're seeing probably means Whitney sum.

Comment: @anomaly Nobody would denote the tensor product of vector spaces as $V_1 \times V_2$, so anyone doing that for vector bundles is committing a horrible crime.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I'm not saying _I_ would. :)  (Come to think of it, I think I have seen $\xi \times \xi'$ used to denote the Whitney sum, though I'd certainly say that $\xi \oplus \xi'$ is far more common.)

Comment: @anomaly It's definitively not the tensor product in this context, so that one is ruled out anyways. Thanks for your response.